# How to write content to a file

Tags: java

```
try {
    File file = new File("sample.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true);
    fw.append('d');
    fw.write(100);
    fw.close();
} catch(IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am unable to append or write anything to the file.

But I could read the content from the file.

Is anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Your code is correct asside from missing the "e" variable name in the catch clause. Please check the path you are running the code from and the permissions. If you are using an ide it or build script it may be wiping out the driectory you are running from before each run.

Comment: @Harry Joy : I didn't get any exception.

Comment: @Neil Essy : I am using Ecllipse Helios. My text file sample.txt is in my workspace. I runned it as a normal java application.

Comment: @Priya I have modified it. This code is working! Giving output as `dd`

Comment: Thak You guys. Its working now. I just restarted my IDE and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you probably *are* writing to a file - but not the file you expect to. If no exceptions have been thrown (and swallowing an exception, just writing it to standard out, is rarely the right approach) then the file will exist *somewhere*.

It will be in whatever directory the code is running from - which may well *not* be the same as the directory containing the `sample.txt` file you're reading. I suggest you explore the file system, and also check the Run Configuration in Eclipse to see what the working directory for the app will be.

As an aside, you should be closing the writer in a `finally` block so that it gets closed even if there's an exception, like this:

```
File file = new File("sample.txt");
FileWriter fw = null;
try {
    fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
    fw.append('d');
    fw.write(100);
} catch(IOException) {
    // Ideally do something to indicate the failure to the caller
    // - do you need to catch this at all?
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    // From Guava
    Closeables.closeQuietly(fw);
}
```

Obviously you can do this without [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) but it'll make things a lot simpler - and not just here. If you're using Java 7 you can make it even simpler with a [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/java-write-to-file.shtml
You can Flush context if code is right and still you are facing problem. it "Flushes the stream"
This link can help!

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma Just to show that her code is right. nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Like was said before the file may be getting cleared out during the build/clean process.  Try specificing an absolute path to the file and running it again.  Everything you have written is correct sans the corrections already offered.

```
try { 
  File file = new File("C:\sample.txt"); // for Windows or possibly just "/sample.txt" for *nix
  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true); 
  fw.append('d'); 
  fw.write(100); 
} catch(IOException e) { 
  e.printStackTrace(); 
} finally { 
  // Good practice to move close to a finally block
  fw.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You may try using the below syntax** :

```
String filename = "C:/sample.txt";

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true);
```